# Fetch table contents based on query form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am supposed to get the contents of a table using a query. Like when people type the Plan Number, it should return all rows with that plan number.

The output should be like this:
[screenshot from php my admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKrTV.jpg)

However, my code only repeats the first one that matches:
[repeated rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXu3Z.jpg)

This is my code:

Controller:

```
public function show_plan(){
    $data['title'] = 'Plan Query';

    if($this->uri->segment(3)=='view'){
        if(!isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){
            redirect(base_url('query/show_plan'));
        }

        $plan = $this->input->post('plan_no_post');

        $this->load->model('plan_query_model');
        $data['items'] = $this->plan_query_model->check_plan($plan);
        $this->load->view('plan_query_view', $data);
    }else{
        $this->load->view('query_form', $data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    public function check_plan($plan){
$this->load->model('report_lookup_model');
        $this->db->where("plan_no='$plan'");
        $rs = $this->db->get('plan_key');
        return $rs->result_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `check_plan` function like this.

```
public function check_plan($plan){
  $this->load->model('report_lookup_model');
  $this->db->where("plan_no", $plan);
  $rs = $this->db->get('plan_key');
  return $rs->result_array();
}
```